# How to pass JSON object and retrieve JSON object in retrofit request in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-adapter, retrofit

I need to pass `Json` in `Post` request using `Retrofit`. My `Json` looks like this:

```
{
  "q": {
         "reg": "IND",
         "or": [
                {
                 "duration": "12"
                }
              ]
       },
 "sort": "recent"
}
```

I created `pojo` for above `Json` using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) which is similar to this: `RoomListing.java` [class](http://pastebin.com/eCZfzvWU)

Now I need to make a `post` request. So I created an `API`

```
public interface RoomListingAPI {

 @GET("/api/fetch")
 void getRoomListing(@Header("x-parse-session-token") String  
 token, @Body RoomListing list);
}
```

Created a `RestAdapter` class

```
 return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();

RoomListingAPI apiservice = restadapter.providesRestAdapter().create(RoomListingAPI.class);
```

Now I am little bit confused to send `Json` (Have a look at RoomListing.java) as `post` request and receive `JSON` in response ?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Why not just send your json as a String?? and you use                        import org.json.JSONArray and import org.json.JSONObject to create json structure.

Comment: I didn't find any example in retrofit to send JSON directly.

Comment: I sent a JSON as a String retrofit/POST give me some minutes and show you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to change the annotation from `@GET` to `@POST` to do a `POST` request. Next, assuming you're using Retrofit 1.9.x, you need to do one of two things to get the resulting JSON response, depending on if you want a synchronous or asynchronous response:

- Synchronous (on the current thread) - change `void` to be of the type of the pojo for the response, similar to how you've made your request object (e.g. `ResponseType yourMethod(@Body RequestType object);`
- Asynchronous (on a different thread, with a callback) - add a `Callback<ResponseType>` to the end of the method, which will then be called on the successful, or unsuccessful,  return of the request (e.g. `void yourMethod(@Body RequestObject object, Callback<ResponseType> callback);`

Comment: I want to get the response in JsonObject  because it's a dynamic JSON

Comment: Then retrofit isn't the best option - look at using something like Volley which gives you JSONObjects - Retrofit is designed to be type safe, covering the "vanilla" case web requests.

Comment: Can't we send JSON object as a post request and receive the JSON object ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public interface RoomListingAPI {

     @POST("/api/fetch")
     void getRoomListing(@Header("x-parse-session-token") String  
     token, @Field("YOURFIELDNAME") String json);
    }


//This method generates your json
private String yourJSON(){

        JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
        try{

            jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);

            jsonObject2.put("duration", "12");

            jsonObject1.put("reg", "IND");
            jsonObject1.put("or", jsonArray);

            jsonRoot.put("q", jsonObject1);
            jsonRoot.put("sort", "recent");

        }catch (JSONException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return jsonRoot.toString();


    }


    RoomListingAPI apiservice = restadapter.providesRestAdapter().create(RoomListingAPI.class);
apiservice.getRoomListing("your_header_token",yourJSON())...
```

I hope you work but it should be something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is no `YOURFIELDNAME ` in my request. I was just passing `JSON` as raw format in `Body`